# react toggle and close when clicked at other element/body failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I want to trigger an expand state when user clicked on certain element, but I failed to implement closing the element when user clicked outside using ref.

Something is wrong with this part:

```
handleClick = e => {
    if (this.node.contains(e.target)) {
      this.setState({
        expand: !this.state.expand // doesn't work?
      },()=>console.log(this.state.expand));

      return;
    }

    this.handleClickOutside();
  };
```

The console triggered twice.

https://codesandbox.io/s/71l34po56x

If you simply change the state of `expand` to `true` in the handleClick you can see the almost working result, but how can I achieve 2 things.

1. User can toggle the content.
2. User clicked on the outside of the content or handler the content will close.

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is when using `arrow(=>)` functions

Comment: That example doesn't seem to show the expanded area.

Comment: @Colin if u do `this.setState({ expand: true })` u can see it.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://codesandbox.io/s/lk7wlzj17

Comment: @Colin yes exactly, what did you changed? but wait, it lost the toggle functionality.

Comment: I'll post an answer, hang on.

Comment: @Colin it doesn't toggle if u hardcoded true for the state.

Comment: If you click anywhere outside, it goes back to the original message. Is that not what you want?

Comment: but when I click on 'click me' it doesn't close it which is not what I want. Try to click on stackoverflow's notification, that's what I want.

Comment: @JamieAden, checkout the answer and let me know your comments, is that you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are attaching the same event handler `handleClick` twice to your `div` (once in `render` function, and also in `componentWillMount`).

That's why when you click on the `div`, you are setting the state twice, and as a result `expand` goes from false to true, then from true to false.

Comment: so any solution? I also know the problem.

Comment: Not the most elegant way of solving this, but something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/n0z8pjonn0) does the job.

What I did is attaching a different event handler to the document (or outside the div), that checks that the clicked element isn't the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can **emit componentWillMount() and componentWillUnmount function** altogether. Then when click is made on div, toggle functionality works perfectly. The thing you are missing here is, when clicks made outside the div, clickhandler() is no more attached to this div, instead it is the root div that gets clicked.

To overcome that, i added a parent div, to occupy maximum height, then use click handlers to expand and toggle the div values.

Below is the code snippet.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center",
  border: "2px solid red",
  height: "500px"
};

const styles2 = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center",
  border: "2px solid black"
};

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    expand: false
  };

  expandedArea() {
    return <div>content area</div>;
  }

  handleClickOutside = () => {
    this.setState({
      expand: false
    });
  };

  handleClick = e => {
    console.log("ddd");
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (this.node.contains(e.target)) {
      this.setState({
        expand: !this.state.expand // doesn't work?
      });

      return;
    }

    this.handleClickOutside();
  };

  render() {
    const { expand } = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={styles} onClick={e => this.handleClickOutside(e)}>
        <div
          style={styles2}
          ref={node => (this.node = node)}
          onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}
        >
          hello world
          {expand && this.expandedArea()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Hope this helps you in what you were looking at, thanks!

Comment: look like a hack